# Smallest Rational Number Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, order-theory, rational-numbers

Can anybody help me out with solving this mathematical proof?

> Prove the statement “There is no smallest rational number greater than
>   2” by contradiction.

**Contradiction**: There is a smallest rational number greater than 2.

I know the above is false because the smallest rational number greater than 2 is a fraction of a decimal 2.00…01 as it gets closer and closer to 2 (by adding more decimal places). Since you can get infinitely closer and closer to 2 there is no exact “smallest rational number”.

However, I'm not sure how to officially prove it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. your classmate was first.

Comment: Any further explanation on that? I'm confused by the accepted answer. I don't see how it proves anything.

Comment: Ask about it in the other thread.